# 2D Array of ArrayLists null exception

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a class that has an ArrayList attribute, and another class that has a 2D Array of that class:

```
public class someThingsList {

    private List<someThings> lst;

    public someThingsList () {
        this.lst = new ArrayList<someThings>();
    }
    public addThing(someThings) {
        someThings s = someThings;
        this.lst.add(s);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class x implements y {

    private static someThingsList[][] field;

    public x(int h, int w) {
    x.field = new someThingsList[h][w];
    for (someThingsList[] lst1 : x.field)
        for (someThingsList lst2 : lst1)
            lst2 = new someThingsList();
}
```

and when I have for example a new x object with (2,2) as h and w, and try to do

```
x.fields[0][0].addThing(thing);
```

I get a NullPointerException error, any idea why?

Comment: Unrelated, but try to name your classes (and interfaces) with a leading uppercase letter and your variables with leading lowercase.  Will make code like `someThings s = someThings;` a lot more readable.

Comment: Oops sorry, that should be
 public addThing(someThings sT) {
        someThings s = sT;
        this.lst.add(s);
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use enhanced for-each loop with arrays when you want to mutate them. `lst2` in your example is just another reference (to `null`), modifying it won't modify the original array. Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < field.length; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < field[i].length; ++j)
        field[i][j] = new someThingsList();
```

or alternatively:

```
for(int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < w; ++j)
        x.field[i][j] = new someThingsList();
```

As a matter of fact, this problem is not specific to arrays. Check the following code:

```
List<String> strings = //...

for(String s: strings) {
    s += "Bar";
}
```

Even though it looks as if you were modifying the original `strings` list, you are barely modifing temporary `s` variable that is recreated and ignore after each loop.

Comment: under the "x.field[i].length" is red with:
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int

Comment: @codeoverflow: just checked with a compiler and it works for me. Maybe the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: under "x.field.length[i]" I meant, sorry, and when i change it to "x.field.length" it works, hmm..

Comment: now it works ;) i had "x.field.length[i]" instead of what you wrote, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have instantiated array `x.field = new someThingsList[h][w];` but you did not instantiate `someThingsList` Object. So x.field[i][j]  gives `NullPointerException`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < x.field.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < x.field[i].length; j++)
        x.field[i][j] = new someThingsList();
```

Comment: under the "x.field[i].length" is red with: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is when you iterate through the second for each loop you are instantiating value of "lst2" which is a local variable to the loop so that it does not affect your original array. As soon as your loop gets over the value of lst2 gets lost. So that your array element remains null and when you try to invoke a method on a null object it gives null pointer exception.

To understand this try to print arr[0]. It will print a object type and then try to print a[0][0] which will print null.

Hope this clears why your syntax is not working.

Try running this code you will understand what is going wrong here.

```
import java.util.*;
class someThingsList {

    private List<String> lst;

    public someThingsList () {
        this.lst = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    public void addThing(String someThings ) {
        String s = someThings;
        this.lst.add(s);
    }
}
class Main{

    private static someThingsList[][] field;

 public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    new Main(3,3);
System.out.println(Main.field[0]);
System.out.println(Main.field[0][0]);
    Main.field[0][0].addThing("thing");
  }

    public Main(int h, int w) {
    Main.field = new someThingsList[h][w];
    for (someThingsList[] lst1 : Main.field)
    {
    System.out.println(lst1);
        for (someThingsList lst2 : lst1){
System.out.println(lst2);
            lst2 = new someThingsList();
System.out.println(lst2);}
    }
    }
}
```